# Timestepping PDE with positive eigenvalues

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I'm trying to numerically solve a PDE, namely:

$$
\partial_t \binom{u(x, t)}{v(x, t)}
= x \left(\begin{array}{cc}
0 & -1 \\ 
1 & 0
\end{array}\right) \cdot
\partial_x \binom{u(x, t)}{v(x, t)}
$$

with some initial condition, and for $x \in \mathbb{R}$.  The problem is however, that it is *expected* that the solution grows unlimited.  So if I see it correctly, no time-stepping scheme at all will be "stable" (because in fact the solution should not be "stable").

In my courses such a situation (where the solution grows) has never been treated, and I also can't find any information on how to solve it.  Probably this is a rather special situation ... so what are the correct numerical schemes for solving something like that?  Which time-stepping and which spatial discretisation should I apply?

So far I tried with implicit Euler and Crank-Nicholson, and used a one-sided difference in space (forward for $x > 0$ and backward for $x < 0$, so I don't need to specify artificial boundary conditions).  This seems to work if the spatial *and* temporal steps are *large*, but it diverges if either one gets too fine.  The problem is, however, that I would like to have a finer discretisation for better accuracy at some point.

Comment: There's a problem with your latex. Should be $$\partial_t \binom{u(x, t)}{v(x, t)}
= x \left(\begin{array}{cc} & -1 \\ 1 & \end{array}\right) \cdot
\partial_x \binom{u(x, t)}{v(x, t)}$$

Comment: Also, I don't know how to answer your numeric problem, but note that one can find the solution analytically. Define
$$z(x,t)\equiv u(x,t)+iv(x,t)\ ,$$
and your equation looks very simple:
$$\partial_t z=ix\partial_x z$$

Comment: Out of interest, where/how did this PDE arise?

Comment: Yes, I didn't get the block-equation formatted, noticed after posting.  @yohBS: Exactly, in fact, the complex version is the original equation.  I put it into the real system to highlight that while the values are complex, the arguments are real (and the $\partial_x$ is not meant as derivative of holomorphic function).

Comment: The analytic solution would be $u_0(e^{it} x)$, when the initial data $u_0$ can be analytically continued.  @in_wolfram_we_trust: Precisely that is the origin, I'm exploring ways to perform numerical analytic continuation of $u_0$.